# How to deprive other apps from using a systemwide/custom broadcast in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcast

I need to check the vulnerability of my app. I am trying to intercept a broadcast message in android such that no other app is able to use that broadcast, is there any way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The closest you can come is if it is an ordered broadcast, if your receiver is higher priority than any other, you can abort the broadcast when you receive it. However, there is nothing preventing some other app from specifying an even higher priority, and where there is a tie (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`), there's a tiebreaker. I think the tiebreaker is first-one-installed wins, as that tiebreaker is used elsewhere.

If the broadcast is not ordered -- IOW, most broadcasts -- then you cannot abort it, and all registered receivers will receive it.

FWIW, I fail to see how preventing broadcasts being delivered to other apps helps "check the vulnerability of [your] app".